# Its not allowing me to compare the dates on the second part of this function

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I need yo be able to compare both dates in this function. This it to make sure that the user has inputted a valid date. For some reason, it will not let me compare the dates.

I have already tried using .date() and switching the dates around and using different operators.

```py
def DateToBook():
    global datestart
    global dateend
    today = date.today()
    print("Today's date is: ", today.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
    while True:

        # This is the date format in which we want the data entered in
        dateformat = '%d/%m/%Y'
        # Allow the user to input what date they would like to book the room
        datestart = input("What date would you like the room to be booked? Type Date dd/mm/yyyy: ")
        try:
            datestart = dt.datetime.strptime(datestart, dateformat) # Checks to see if the format matches
        except ValueError:
            print("Incorrect format")   # Tells the user that the format is wrong
            # Makes them try again
        else:
            if datestart.date() < today:
                print("Invalid date")
            else:
                datestart = datestart.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')  # This takes off the unnecessary parts
                break # Carries on the program if no errors are found

    while True:
        # Allow the user to enter the date the booking will end
        dateend = input("What date would you like the booking to end? Type Data dd/mm/yyyy: ")
        try:
            dateend = dt.datetime.strptime(dateend, dateformat)
        except ValueError:
            print("Incorrect format")
        else:
            if datestart.date() > dateend:   # Throws error
                print("Enter a valid date")
            else:
                dateend = dateend.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')  # This takes off the unnecessary parts
                break
```

Comment: Add the error you are getting to your question... It will help us answer you a lot easier

Comment: It's not an error, sorry. It just does not work, it does not compare the dates

Comment: I answered below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first while loop ends by turning `datestart` into a string. This makes it unable to apply the `.date()` method in the second while loop. Try naming the new string version of `datestart` something different...

```
def DateToBook():
    global datestart
    global dateend
    today = date.today()
    print("Today's date is: ", today.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
    while True:

        # This is the date format in which we want the data entered in
        dateformat = '%d/%m/%Y'
        # Allow the user to input what date they would like to book the room
        datestart = input("What date would you like the room to be booked? Type Date dd/mm/yyyy: ")
        try:
            datestart = dt.datetime.strptime(datestart, dateformat) # Checks to see if the format matches
        except ValueError:
            print("Incorrect format")   # Tells the user that the format is wrong
            # Makes them try again
        else:
            if datestart.date() < today:
                print("Invalid date")
            else:
                str_datestart = datestart.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')  # This takes off the unnecessary parts
                break # Carries on the program if no errors are found

    while True:
        # Allow the user to enter the date the booking will end
        dateend = input("What date would you like the booking to end? Type Data dd/mm/yyyy: ")
        try:
            dateend = dt.datetime.strptime(dateend, dateformat)
        except ValueError:
            print("Incorrect format")
        else:
            if datestart.date() > dateend:   # Throws error
                print("Enter a valid date")
            else:
                str_dateend = dateend.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')  # This takes off the unnecessary parts
                break
```